# htaccess redirect loop directory to php file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^cart.php(.*?) https://www.DOMAIN.com/buy-now/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^buy-now/(.*?) cart.php$1 [QSA]
```

This creates a redirect loop. What i want is for **cart.php** to redirect to **/buy-now/** (carrying query strings) and **/buy-now/** to actually parse as **cart.php**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this will sure cause loop. You will need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` to avoid this looping.

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /+cart\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^cart\.php(.*)$ /buy-now/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^buy-now/(.*)$ /cart.php$1 [L,NC]
```

- `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

Comment: Don't think `(.*)` is required since he wants to retain the query string so perhaps just add `QSA` to it, since query string are not available on the `(.*)`.

Comment: okay thanks. i was trying something similar to that but i used %{REQUEST_URI} for some reason... wrong variable.

Comment: @Prix: Actually `QSA` isn't even needed since OP is not passing `$1` in query string.

Comment: @anubhava `to redirect to /buy-now/ (carrying query strings)` so I am assuming he thinks `(.*?)` will catch the query strings which doesn't, which is why I don't think they are needed on your sample and rather the use of `QSA` would have been more suitable.

Comment: Yes I have seen that `carrying query strings` and `QSA` is not the flag for this since that is default behavior anyway. `QSA` is ONLY needed when rule is adding a new query parameter and you want to preserve existing query string.

Comment: @b747fp yes it should but will have overhead from the unneeded parts that's all.